# In a damped harmonic oscillator, what exactly is $b$ in the equation $F_{damping}=-bv$, and does it ever change?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, mass, friction, harmonic-oscillator

Does $b$ change as mass changes? I've experimented with a mass-spring system damped in water and recorded it using video tracking software. Using the Logger Pro's "Damped Harmonic Model Fit" I get values for $-B$, which result in distinctly different values of $b$ when multiplying by $2m$.

Comment: Did you only change the mass or the volume as well?

Answer (score 1):

The $b$ you're referring to is just supposed to be a constant that depends on the medium the mass is in (i.e. air, water, etc) and the shape of the mass. It shouldn't change with the value of the mass, though it would probably change if the shape of the mass changed. Lastly, this model of saying $F_{damping} = -bv$ is based on the assumption that the damping is small. Therefore, if you're using it for when the mass is in water (and thus the damping is large), this approximation may no longer be accurate (you could instead try using $F_{damping} = -bv^2$ for when the mass is in water, but even that may be inaccurate).

Comment: Thanks. I guess it changed because I was using slotted masses, so for each additional 100g mass, the shape and surface area of the oscillator changed. However, my value for $b$ practically doubled (from 200 ish to around 400 ish) when going from 100g to 700g slotted masses. Is this normal? Thanks.

Comment: It's hard to say; it could be that our model of using $F_{damping} = -bv$ is invalid and we need to include higher order terms (i.e. $v^2$), or it could be totally reasonable that slight alterations in the shape change the constant. I'm not really sure to be honest.